# How to keep focus on my application and prevent changing cursor when moving outside the form?

Tags: c#, forms

My C# program allows user click outside the form to set the coordinates of some points on the screen.

The problem is when user clicks outside the app form, my program is out of focus. Instead, the clicked application will be focused.

Is it possible to keep focus on the app and when the cursor moving, hovering on another apps like a textbox, notepad..., it doesn't transform to another form?